# Unloading cached html5 videos on video-heavy site?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Is there a way to unload videos from cache that have been dynamically added to a page?
I'm implementing a video heavy site which is designed to load all it's videos through Javascript.

I would love some links to resources on that issue.

btw.: I would like to add that wihtout unloading, the sites bloats up in memory of my Safari browser to up to 2GB in RAM! ... :S

Comment: Are you using the same HTML5 elements to load the videos, or are you creating new elements for each video?  If the latter, I wonder if the DOM elements are lingering around with links to content that would otherwise be purged. </wildSpeculation>

Comment: I'm inserting new elements each time, but I .remove() them through jQuery after the videos have played.

Comment: Make sure all references are removed, and event listeners, and references in closures.

Comment: It's been a while, any solutions to this?